# Association of a single property from different table in EF 4.3

Tags: .net, entity-framework, associations, edmx

I have two tables with the following definitions:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shows] (
    [Id]              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Name]            NVARCHAR (1024)  NOT NULL,
    [Image]           NVARCHAR (1024)  NULL,
    [Description]     NTEXT            NULL,
    [Seasons]         INT              NOT NULL,
    [FacebookId]      BIGINT           NULL,
    [BackgroundImage] NVARCHAR (200)   NULL,
    [TheTvDbId]       BIGINT           NULL,
    [NetworkId]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Shows] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Shows_ToNetworks] FOREIGN KEY ([NetworkId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Networks] ([Id])
);

        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TheTvDb]
    (
        [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL, 
        [EntityId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
        [TheTvDbId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
        [LastUpdated] BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
        CONSTRAINT [AK_TheTvDb_EntityId] UNIQUE ([EntityId]),
        CONSTRAINT [AK_TheTvDb_TheTvDbId] UNIQUE ([TheTvDbId])
    )
```

What I want to do is to create an association property `TheTvDbLastUpdated` on the `Shows` table that points to the property `LastUpdated` of table `TheTvDb`. The key linking `TheTvDb` record with `Shows` record is `EntityId`. The relationship is one to one. I know how to create association that will link to the whole `TheTvDbTable` but I do not know how to link only to this one property, which would make it more convenient to access it from the generated entity classes. Thanks.

I use database-first approach, so I'm looking for a way to do it from the designer of the .edmx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Properties that "point" to something are references/navigation properties. You can't make a scalar/value type a navigation property.

A convenient helper might be a readonly helper property (implemented in partial class file, not EDMX):

```
public partial class Show
{
    public long TheTvDbLastUpdated { get { return this.TheTvDb.LastUpdated; } }
}
```

Where `TheTvDb` would be the one-to-one navigation property from `Show` to `TheTvDb`. If you use lazy loading accessing this property would load the `TheTvDb` entity from the database first if it hasn't been already loaded yet. If you don't use lazy loading `TheTvDb` can be `null` and accessing the property would cause an exception. You might catch this case:

```
public long TheTvDbLastUpdated
{
    get
    {
        if (this.TheTvDb == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "TheTvDbLastUpdated cannot be accessed before TheTvDb is loaded.");
        return this.TheTvDb.LastUpdated;
    }
}
```

Anyway, you need the navigation property for this, and it doesn't look like a big win if you write `show.TheTvDbLastUpdated` instead of `show.TheTvDb.LastUpdated` (actually the win is just saving one single dot).

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative solution - you are using database first so you can simply create a view which will offer your projection and map the view instead of tables. The new entity will be read only because EF doesn't know how to update original tables hidden behind the view - this limitation can be solved by mapping stored procedures to insert, update and delete functionality.

View can also solve other problems EF will have with your database

- It looks like your `TheTvDb` doesn't have primary key - table without primary key is readonly in EF
- You are trying to build one-to-one relation between `Shows.Id` and `TheTvDb.EntityId`. In your database the relation is one-to-one because you have unique constraint on `EntityId` but in EF this relation will be one-to-many because EF doesn't support unique constraints yet